# Workbench is including a table that was already deleted

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, workbench

For some reason workbench is including a table on the output script which i removed long time ago.

As result, when running the script it identifies the following error. 
I know that removing it from the script solves my problem but i can't figure out were the hell workbench is getting that table.

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8' at line 2

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `FestockDb`.`Film_has_CastEntitie` (
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8

SQL script execution finished: statements: 254 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's an old question but I ran into this problem also and maybe it could help all the other that will have this problem.
As you said you **only REMOVED** the table from the EER diagram and not **DELETED** it.
In order to fully delete this table look at the left side pane
under "catalog" you can see all of the tables you ever created including the ones you removed, The not bolded tables are the ones which you only removed.
The only way to delete them is to **DRAG** them back to the table sketch view section and then right click to delete.

Now when you'll output the script you won't see those old tables any more.